# Как создать подобие личного кабинета пользователя в Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс

Стоит задача: 
Есть группа из 50ти сотрудников для которых нужно создать личные страницы. Сотрудники просто заполнят свои личные данные и периодически будут заливать документы через сайт на вебсервер.
1) На странице должны отображаться их ФИО и прочие личные данные (желательно с возможностью их изменить).
2) На странице должно быть собственное файловое хранилище на которое можно заливать свои документы (например компонент "библиотека документов для работы с инфоблоком")

Вопрос:
- По 1) -ому пункту. Каким образом можно вывести данные пользователя на страницу? 
- По 2) -ому пункту. У каждого должно быть личное хранилище без возможности смотреть чужие. Мне придется 50 штук клепать или можно сделать привязку к ID пользователя? 
- Общий. Как мне не формировать 50 страниц с собственными хранилищами, и личными данными аккаунта пользователя, а создать только одну, которая будет отображать данные в зависимости от ID пользователя и соответственно отображать и определенное хранилище?

Буду рад коду или совету по использованию компонента. Корпоративный портал 12.0.5 Спасибо.

Comment: эм, может стоит обновить уже версию корпоративного портала?:) или там все так плохо

Comment: Найти тех кто помнит напамять доку по этой версии. Проще всего обновиться до актуальной версии в которой уже это все есть и не придется ломать голову. Ядро шагнуло далеко вперед и доков по старым версиям нет, даже теоретически помочь тяжело.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По пунктам:

1. Если не путаю в названиях, есть компонент `bitrix:main.profile`, можно смело использовать его
2. Так как версия 12.0.5, наверное там "Мой диск" и т.п. нет, и честно, с ним не работал на уровне API, можно просто реализовать Инфоблок "Документы пользователей" и одним из свойств сделать привязку к пользователю, и все, ваше "файловое хранилище" документов готово, дальше просто реализуйте добавление и редактирование записи